# What does this git log mean?

Tags: git

this is the recent log of the git.

```
commit 608991c
Merge: 5c0c062 1fe65f9
Author: foo
Date:   Mon Jul 2 

    Merge branch 'mybranch' of xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/myproject into mybranch

    Conflicts:
        bar.c
```

Does this log mean the user foo does a merge operation?

Answer (score 2):

As described in "[Merging With a Conflict: Conflicts And Resolutions](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/merging-with-a-conflict-conflicts-and-resolutions/)", this is the automatic log message generated after the resolution of a merge with conflicts.

You can see that message built in [git source file `builtin/merge.c`, in the `suggest_conflicts()` function](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/merge.c#L969-L979)

```
static int suggest_conflicts(int renormalizing)
{
    const char *filename;
    FILE *fp;
    int pos;

    filename = git_path("MERGE_MSG");
    fp = fopen(filename, "a");
    if (!fp)
        die_errno(_("Could not open '%s' for writing"), filename);
    fprintf(fp, "\nConflicts:\n");
```

---

From a user point of view:

> #### Resolve the conflict
>
> After we have resolved the conflict (by changing the `README` file the way we want for this git merge), we have to tell git that the conflict is resolved by adding the conflicted file to the index.
>
> In this case, we need to add `README` to the git index.
> `git status` will then no longer complain about the `README` file having a conflict:

```
$ git add README
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#
#   modified:   README
#   new file:   plan
#
```

> We're ready to commit the merge:

```
$ git commit
[master 368a14a] Merge branch 'test'
```

> The git log command shows the resolved conflict:

```
$ git log
commit 368a14a034eda95ee401bb56b3bb8df04b84ab0c
Merge: 3330113 c406564
Author: Tim Flagg 
Date:   Fri Mar 25 13:26:10 2011 -0700

    Merge branch 'test'

    Conflicts:
        README
```

> `gitg --all` shows the merge:

[image: merge in logs]